# bash: move new file as soon as it is written

Tags: bash, loops, move

I'm trying to write a bash script to move files from a source to a destination, in order to save space on the disk of the source (source and destination are two different machines).

I can handle the moving part by using the scp protocol, but the problem is that the software I'm using writes a lot of files very quickly (luckily each file has the same extension) and I want to move a file as soon as it is written.

So, in the directory of the source, I'd like to:

- move the file on the destination,
- remove the file from the source,

... until the software stops to write new files on the source.

Any help?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/14252/how-in-a-script-can-i-determine-if-a-file-is-currently-being-written-to-by-ano

Comment: @sam_dc - How do you imagine to detect when _the software stops to write new files on the source_?

Comment: You might consider not writing to a file *at all*. Write to a named pipe, from which you can read with a command like `ssh remotehost 'cat > destination'` to "stream" the file to the remote host using only a constant amount of local disk space.

Comment: You want to move all files? You could just mount the destination at source with sshfs and make it write to remote by itself.

Comment: @chepner Unfortunately I can not control the output of my software

Comment: @Armali I can do it quite easily by checking the .log file.

Comment: So this _checking the .log file_ is not a part where you ask for help? Then it's confusing that you mentioned it in the question.

Answer (score 0):

This is a job for `inotifywait`.

```
inotifywait -meclose_write . |
while read d e f
do
    echo Now is the time to move "$f".
done
```

Of course you can specify any source directory instead of `.`.

Comment: It *may* be a job for `inotifywait`, which is specific to Linux. Other operating systems have similar mechanisms for monitoring the file system as well.